# Put a lottie animation in a Dialog. Android

Tags: android, dialog, lottie

I'm developing an app in android, and I want to use lottie for a Dialog that could have an animated icon of checked-done or fail. Wellcome some examples or ideas. I guess this is possible.
Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android

Comment: I know about this, but i'm not using kotlin, I use java, so any recomendation for using lottie or another option. Thanks

Comment: that is java...

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using the LottieDialog library

Github Repo for examples and documentation : [LottieDialog](https://github.com/amrdeveloper/lottiedialog)

Code example:

```java
Button button = new Button(this);
button.setText("Ok");
button.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
button.setAllCaps(false);
int greenColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.green);
button.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(greenColor));

LottieDialog dialog = new LottieDialog(this)
        .setAnimation(R.raw.success_like)
        .setAnimationRepeatCount(LottieDialog.INFINITE)
        .setAutoPlayAnimation(true)
        .setDialogBackground(Color.WHITE)
        .setMessage("Task is Done :D")
        .setMessageColor(greenColor)
        .addActionButton(button);

dialog.show();
```

You can add more buttons, or create it with no buttons,

[image]